# Rails I18n: shorten the translate calls (at least in the views)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, method-call, abbreviation

What is the DRY way to translate certain fields?

In my RESTful views, I have some repeating snippets, like this in a show-view:

```
...
<dt><%= t("activerecord.attributes.user.firstname") %></dt>
<dd><%= @user.firstname %></dd>
...
```

Now, instead of writing `t("activerecord.attributes.user.attr_name")` over and over again, I'd like to write only `t(:attr_name)` (similar to `f.label :firstname` in the form-views).

Basically, this should not be a problem (at least for the RESTful views), since the I18n module could query the `controller` method to extrapolate the model name and then just guess the correct translation string.

My question: Did anyone have practical experience with this approach? Could there even be a RubyGem for it? Or: are there pitfalls, I didn't think of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seems, [`ActiveModel::Translation#human_attribute_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-human_attribute_name) does the trick (e.g. `<%= User.human_attribute_name :firstname %>`).

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is to put this into a partial (e.g. `app/views/user/_form.html.erb` or even `app/views/user/_user.html.erb`), and then precede the name with a leading dot, thus:

```
<dt><%= t(".firstname") %></dt>
<dd><%= user.firstname %></dd>
```

More information: [examples](http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-192-30/section-15.3.html) (from [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)); [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate)

Comment: The usage of partials seems to be quiet nice, but I think it will only be DRY, if the same content will be displayed repetively. The documentation also says, calling `t('.foo')` from the people/index.html.erb template is actually calling `t('people.index.foo')`. I don't want to maintain the mess in my locale files...